# Node Red - external modules won't load to palette

Tags: npm, node-red

I've installed the Particle and the arduino library with npm. In the 'Users/greg'(mac os x) I can see the node-modules folder and all the above mentioned libraries but they won't appear in the editor. I've tried 'Import-Library' but the menu is broken. Any ideas?

Comment: Steps to reproduce your problem would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modules need to be installed into 1 of 2 specific location to be used by Node-RED as described in the *Adding Nodes* documentation [here](http://nodered.org/docs/getting-started/adding-nodes.html)

Import-Library is for importing flows not Node-RED Nodes.

Running `npm install <node name>` in your home directory will not install nodes in one of these locations.

Nodes should be installed either globally or in the `.node-red` directory in your home directory.

To install them globally you need to add the `-g` flag to the install:

```
npm install -g <node name>
```

To install into the .node-red directory you needs to be in that directory before running the install command:

```
cd ~/.node-red
npm install <node name>
```

You will need to restart Node-RED to have it pick up the new nodes.

Comment: Thank you hardlib but it seems that I have done everything the way you described it yet the modules won't appear. I cd-d to .node-red then installed a library with 'npm install' and the module (or any modules installed) won't appear. UPDATE: 'npm install -g' worked with a library, thank you!

Comment: Edit your original question to include all of the commands you ran

Answer (score 1):

on your node-red dashboard click the triple lines in the top right

then click "Manage palette"

then click the "install" tab on the palette manager

search for your library and install it

Comment: Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and format your reply.